# Date separators not working properly in 64 bit Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am on a Windows 10 x64 machine with 64 bit Excel 2016 installed.

I am having trouble with the dates as they are not working properly, I have regional settings set properly, but VBA does not seem to properly recognize `.` as Date separator, it only uses `-`. When I compare this to a Windows 7 x64 machine with 32 bit Excel 2010 installed it works the way it should.

In the picture below, you can see the incorrect behavior:

[image: VBA behavior]

Basically, I am calling:

```
? cdate("01.08.2016")
15. 06. 4862 
? cdate("01-08-2016")
1. 08. 2016 
? Application.International(xlDateSeparator)
.
? Application.International(xlTimeSeparator)
:
```

I have no idea why this is not working as it should as the regional settings of Windows are set correctly.. any ideas?

Comment: From your screenshoot, it looks like your setting has space after the dots , `d. MM. yyyy` and not `d.MM.yyyy`, but you are trying to convert `"01.08.2016"` without spaces. Try to convert `"01. 08. 2016"`instead.

Comment: @VincentG indeed, that was the problem.. those darn spaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution.. I had to change short date in regional settings to:

```
d.MM.yyyy
```

The previous settings had spaces in the short date mask (as noted by VincentG) like this:

```
d. MM. yyyy
```

This is how my settings look like now:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing it's getting confused by the `.` and trying to use it as a thousands separator (by removing it):

```
Debug.Print Format$(CDate(1082016), "dd.mm.yyyy") 'prints 15.06.4862
```

Excel and VBA are really bad with dates and localization.  I'd suggest a workaround like this:

```
Dim test As String
Dim parts() As String
test = "01.08.2016"
parts = Split(test, Application.International(xlDateSeparator))
Debug.Print DateSerial(CInt(parts(2)), CInt(parts(0)), CInt(parts(1)))
```